# ASP.NET Web API - difference between Async and Synchronous method in browser's Network Console

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to understand this code that I just found in this [link](https://github.com/KevinDockx/AspNetCoreAsyncBestPracticesJetBrainsWebinar/blob/master/Books.Api/Controllers/BooksController.cs):

I'm curious of what's the difference when between using the asynchronous and synchronous method in the Web API:

Asynchronous:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetBook")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBookWithBookCovers(Guid id)
{
    var bookEntity = await _booksRepository.GetBookAsync(id);

    if (bookEntity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // get bookcovers
    var bookCovers = await _booksRepository.GetBookCoversAsync(id);

    // map book & covers into one BookWithCovers
    var mappedBook = _mapper.Map<BookWithCovers>(bookEntity);
    return Ok(_mapper.Map(bookCovers, mappedBook));
}
```

Synchronous:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetBook")]
public IActionResult GetBookWithBookCovers(Guid id)
{
    var bookEntity = _booksRepository.GetBook(id);

    if (bookEntity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // get bookcovers
    var bookCovers = _booksRepository.GetBookCovers(id);

    // map book & covers into one BookWithCovers
    var mappedBook = _mapper.Map<BookWithCovers>(bookEntity);
    return Ok(_mapper.Map(bookCovers, mappedBook));
}
```

If there is a long running query in one of the codes of these two methods, what will be the behavior in the network console of browser?

Is the asynchronous method going to return a status code 202 while the query is running? or it will error out and saying like query timeout?

Comment: There is no difference. async/await is a C# implementation detail that has no effect on the HTTP protocol.

Comment: make ur console app multi threaded, aka call the same url 50 times at the same time, the async version will be able to deal with this better than the sync version. So you should see async handle more requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ian Kemp said *"async/await ... has no effect on the HTTP protocol"*.

#### Client perspective

There is not difference. The same OK status code would return in both cases if no exception would occur during the request processing.

Sync or Async processing should be considered as an implementation detail. If you would have a OpenAPI documentation (a.k.a Swagger) then the two methods would look exactly the same.

#### Server perspective

Your ASP.NET WebAPI would not return anything to the caller until it reaches the end of the Controller's Action.

The await keyword says:

- There is possibly a long-running operation.
- The executing `Thread` can't move on to the next statement, because it relies on the result of the async operation.
- Because the `Thread` can't do anything with this request, it would make sense to return to the `ThreadPool` and assign a new job to it (for example another request) until the async operation is running.
- When that async operation is finished the `ThreadPool` will be notified and it will schedule the remaining of the Controller's Action to the appropriate `Thread`.

The async/await was designed (primarily) to support non-blocking async I/O operations. That means while the network driver handles the I/O request until that time the computation executors (Threads) could work on other things.

So in short, async/await gives you scalability (bigger throughput) for server applications.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. Now the next thing in my mind now is if there is a way to pull a long running query from the server side (web api in azure app service) since its timeout is irreplaceable and I need to make asynchronous pattern as per the answer in this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05f254a6-9b34-4eb2-a5f7-2a82fb40135f/time-out-after-230-seconds?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: @ajgo I think it's worth opening a new question to discuss this topic separately. Do you agree?